# Grails/Dojo Progress bar getting progress from controller/service

Tags: ajax, grails, dojo

Currently I'm using Grails to create a web-based data loading application that in short, takes an excel sheet of arbitrary rows and runs them through a backend system to prep the data for testers.

Everything is working fine, but the last thing I need is some method to inform the user (especially on LARGE data files) of how many rows of data it has processed.  If there's more than 200 rows, the app will (appear) to time out even though its still chugging along.  This is a problem because it's very likely the user will reload the file and mess up processing... duplicate test data rows will cause a bunch of downstream issues.

I'm playing with the code [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/ProgressBar.html).

```
<g:actionSubmit action="${appContext}/FileUploader.processFile" value="Upload File" onclick="download()"></g:actionSubmit>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dijit.ProgressBar");
    dojo.require("dojo.parser");

    var i = 0;
    function download() {
        jsProgress.update({
            maximum: 10,
            progress: ++i
        });
        if (i < 10) {
            setTimeout(download, 100 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
        }
    }
</script>
```

Currently in my controller I have a small method that does this:

```
def updateStatus = {
    render uploaderService.rowsLoaded / uploaderService.listToSend.size()
}
```

What I can't seem to figure out is the correct way to call the method to get the percentage to link to the progress bar.  (replacing the boilerplate `progress` code.)

I know Java well enough but getting *this* to work just seems a little mystifying.

I'm willing to entertain ANY idea of getting progress out there whether or not its technically best-practice... I'm to the point where I just need SOMETHING to display this information.  It doesn't have to be dojo, it's just the direction that I had the most initial success with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you may want to kick off the processes in a background job and return a processing message to the user

Here's an example of how to do this using the jprogress and executer plugins. Unfortunately, this uses a polling solution. I haven't figured out how to use JMS to trigger the updates yet.

Domain

```
package jprogressdemo

class Event {

    String name
    Integer duration = 100
    String status = "New"
    Integer percentComplete = 0

    static mapping = {
      cache false
    }

    static constraints = {
        name(size:1..45, unique:true )
        duration()
        status(size:1..5)
        percentComplete()
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package jprogressdemo

class EventController {

    //static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]
    def progressService
    def jmsService


    static exposes = ['jms']
    static destination = "queue.notification"


    def executeAction = {

        println "executeAction"

        def theEvent    = Event.get(params.id)

        def duration    = theEvent?.duration ?: 10
        def name        = theEvent?.name.trim() ?: "none"
        def startAt     = theEvent?.percentComplete ?: 0

        toEvent(name,duration,startAt,true)

        render "the progress is done"
    }

    /*
     * Start the backgorund task then
     * while %complete < 100, query db and update progressbar.
     */

    //the progress bar id needs to the same value that's passed into .setProgressBarValue
    def backgroundAction = {

        println "backgroundAction"

        println "isDisabled():${jmsService.isDisabled()}"

        def theEvent    = Event.get(params.id)

        def duration    = theEvent?.duration ?: 10
        def name        = theEvent?.name ?: "none"
        def barName        = "${name}b"
        def percentComplete     = theEvent?.percentComplete ?: 0
        def lastPct             = -1

        runAsync { 
            toEvent(name,duration,percentComplete,false)
        }

        if (percentComplete > 100) {progressService.setProgressBarValue(barName, 100)}  
        //can't be factored out because it's this function that 
        // gets called from the client ????
        while(percentComplete <= 100) {
            println "percentComplete:${percentComplete}"
            if (percentComplete != lastPct ) {
                progressService.setProgressBarValue(barName, percentComplete)
                lastPct = percentComplete
            }
            def newEvent    = Event.get(params.id)
            newEvent.refresh()
            percentComplete = theEvent.percentComplete
        }


        render "the progress is done"
    }


    //the progress bar id needs to the same value that's passed into .setProgressBarValue
    def backgroundProgress = {

        def theEvent    = Event.get(params.id)

        def duration    = theEvent?.duration ?: 10
        def name        = theEvent?.name ?: "none"
        def barName        = "${name}p"
        def percentComplete     = theEvent?.percentComplete ?: 0
        def lastPct             = -1

        if (percentComplete > 100) {progressService.setProgressBarValue(barName, 100)}  

        while(percentComplete <= 100) {
            println "percentComplete:${percentComplete}"
            if (percentComplete != lastPct ) {
                progressService.setProgressBarValue(barName, percentComplete)
                lastPct = percentComplete
            }
            def newEvent    = Event.get(params.id)
            newEvent.refresh()
            percentComplete = theEvent.percentComplete
        }

    }
    /*

    % complete needs to get to 101 to avoid infinit loop in polling logic
    And you can't go from 0-99 because the progress bar doesn't register a 0

     */

    def toEvent(name,duration,startAt,updateBar) {

        println "duration:${duration}"
        println "name:${name}"
        println "startat:${startAt}"

        for (int i = startAt; i < 102; i++) {

            println "i:${i}"

            def theEvent = Event.findByName(name)
            theEvent.percentComplete = i
            theEvent.save(flush:true)
            println "theEvent.percentComplete:${theEvent.percentComplete}"

            if(updateBar){
                progressService.setProgressBarValue(name, i)
            } else {
                sendJMSMessage("queue.notification", "${i}")
            }

            //let's waste some time
            for (int a = 0; a < duration; a++) {

                for (int b = 0; b < 1000; b++) {

                }
            }
        }
    }



    def index = {
        redirect(action: "list", params: params)
    }

    def list = {
        params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)
        [eventInstanceList: Event.list(params), eventInstanceTotal: Event.count()]
    }

    def create = {
        def eventInstance = new Event()
        eventInstance.properties = params
        return [eventInstance: eventInstance]
    }

    def save = {
        def eventInstance = new Event(params)
        if (eventInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'event.label', default: 'Event'), eventInstance.id])}"
            redirect(action: "show", id: eventInstance.id)
        }
        else {
            render(view: "create", model: [eventInstance: eventInstance])
        }
    }

    def show = {
        def eventInstance = Event.get(params.id)
        if (!eventInstance) {
            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'event.label', default: 'Event'), params.id])}"
            redirect(action: "list")
        }
        else {
            [eventInstance: eventInstance]
        }
    }

    def edit = {
        def eventInstance = Event.get(params.id)
        if (!eventInstance) {
            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'event.label', default: 'Event'), params.id])}"
            redirect(action: "list")
        }
        else {
            return [eventInstance: eventInstance]
        }
    }

    def update = {
        def eventInstance = Event.get(params.id)
        if (eventInstance) {
            if (params.version) {
                def version = params.version.toLong()
                if (eventInstance.version > version) {

                    eventInstance.errors.rejectValue("version", "default.optimistic.locking.failure", [message(code: 'event.label', default: 'Event')] as Object[], "Another user has updated this Event while you were editing")
                    render(view: "edit", model: [eventInstance: eventInstance])
                    return
                }
            }
            eventInstance.properties = params
            if (!eventInstance.hasErrors() && eventInstance.save(flush: true)) {
                flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'event.label', default: 'Event'), eventInstance.id])}"
                redirect(action: "show", id: eventInstance.id)
            }
            else {
                render(view: "edit", model: [eventInstance: eventInstance])
            }
        }
        else {
            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'event.label', default: 'Event'), params.id])}"
            redirect(action: "list")
        }
    }

    def delete = {
        def eventInstance = Event.get(params.id)
        if (eventInstance) {
            try {
                eventInstance.delete(flush: true)
                flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'event.label', default: 'Event'), params.id])}"
                redirect(action: "list")
            }
            catch (org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
                flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'event.label', default: 'Event'), params.id])}"
                redirect(action: "show", id: params.id)
            }
        }
        else {
            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'event.label', default: 'Event'), params.id])}"
            redirect(action: "list")
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
<%@ page import="jprogressdemo.Event" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="layout" content="main" />
   <g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>
  <jqui:resources/>
  <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'event.label', default: 'Event')}" />
  <title><g:message code="default.show.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <span class="menuButton"><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message code="default.home.label"/></a></span>
    <span class="menuButton"><g:link class="list" action="list"><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></span>
    <span class="menuButton"><g:link class="create" action="create"><g:message code="default.new.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></span>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <h1><g:message code="default.show.label" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
    <g:if test="${flash.message}">
      <div class="message">${flash.message}</div>
    </g:if>
    <div class="dialog">
      <table>
        <tbody>

          <tr class="prop">
            <td valign="top" class="name"><g:message code="event.id.label" default="Id" /></td>

        <td valign="top" class="value">${fieldValue(bean: eventInstance, field: "id")}</td>

        </tr>

        <tr class="prop">
          <td valign="top" class="name"><g:message code="event.name.label" default="Name" /></td>

        <td valign="top" class="value">${fieldValue(bean: eventInstance, field: "name")}</td>

        </tr>

        <tr class="prop">
          <td valign="top" class="name"><g:message code="event.duration.label" default="Duration" /></td>

        <td valign="top" class="value">${fieldValue(bean: eventInstance, field: "duration")}</td>

        </tr>

        <tr class="prop">
          <td valign="top" class="name"><g:message code="event.status.label" default="Status" /></td>

        <td valign="top" class="value">${fieldValue(bean: eventInstance, field: "status")}</td>

        </tr>

        <tr class="prop">
          <td valign="top" class="name"><g:message code="event.percentComplete.label" default="Percent Complete" /></td>

        <td valign="top" class="value">${fieldValue(bean: eventInstance, field: "percentComplete")}</td>

        </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <g:form>
        <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${eventInstance?.id}" />
        <span class="button"><g:actionSubmit class="edit" action="edit" value="${message(code: 'default.button.edit.label', default: 'Edit')}" /></span>
        <span class="button"><g:actionSubmit class="delete" action="delete" value="${message(code: 'default.button.delete.label', default: 'Delete')}" onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message', default: 'Are you sure?')}');" /></span>
      </g:form>
    </div>
    <p>
    <HR WIDTH="75%" COLOR="#FF0000" SIZE="4"/>
    <g:form>
      <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${eventInstance?.id}"/>   
      <g:submitToRemote action="executeAction"  name="startButton" value="start...."/>
      <g:submitToRemote action="backgroundAction"  name="backgroundButton" value="background...."/>
      <g:submitToRemote action="backgroundProgress"  name="progressButton" value="progress...."/>
    </g:form>

    <g:jprogress progressId="${eventInstance?.name}" trigger="startButton"/>
    <g:jprogress progressId="${eventInstance?.name}b" trigger="backgroundButton"/>
    <g:jprogress progressId="${eventInstance?.name}p" trigger="progressButton"/>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had some weird dependency issues with SSTS to get through... but this gets the necessary result.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the CometD plugin to publish messages to a topic, and have your progressbar subscribe to that topic...

http://metasieve.wordpress.com/2010/08/25/using-cometd-2-x-with-grails/